# How to fetch all the data from Smartsheet using API?

Tags: python, smartsheet-api

I am trying to fetch all the rows that are existing in an Smartsheet using API.
I have generated the bearer authorization token and have the report details. My Python is fetching me results of the first 100 rows (source has 1200 rows). I don't use any filters within the Python. Is this due to any default (page-size value)?

I am unable to retrieve all existing data from this API.

Answer (score 2):

With the Smartsheet Python SDK, the `get_sheet` operation (in **sheets.py**) specifies the default page size as 100. 
[image: get_sheet]

You should be able to override this value by specifying the **page_size** parameter when you call the **get_sheet** operation.

Comment: I am using the def getData operation. Will i be able to override the default value of the page_size within this operation?

Comment: Are you using the Smartsheet Python SDK (https://github.com/smartsheet-platform/smartsheet-python-sdk)?  If so, and your objective is to "fetch all the rows that exist in a sheet", then you can use the "get_sheet" operation to do this. I'm not clear on what you mean by "getData operation". Please edit your original question (above) to add the source code that you're using to get sheet data (omitting your access token, of course).

Comment: No, i am not using the smartsheet python sdk, my code looks like below,
def getData(self, page, getToken, token, proxy)

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear from your question if you are reading a sheet or a report. Sample code would be very helpful.

The report API `get_report(report_id, page_size=100, page=1, include=None)` also allows you to specify the number of results to return. However, note that you can read a maximum of 500 rows at a time from a report. So you would need to use a loop.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve this by using a curl command from SSH and calling it Talend.

```
curl -X GET -H 'Authorization: Bearer YOURBEARERTOKENGOESHERE' https://YOURREPORTURL -k -i
```